# Doctrine 2 asociacion uno a muchos bidireccional no está funcionando

Tags: php, doctrine2, symfony, zend

estoy usando Doctrine 2 en con Zend Framework 3 para generar una asociacion uno a muchos, pero cuando ejecuto el comando orm:validate-schema para validar los mapeos me da el siguiente error:

"C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor\vendor\bin>doctrine-module orm:validate-schema [Mapping] FAIL - The entity-class 'Empleados\Entity\TipoDocumento' mapping is i nvalid: * The association Empleados\Entity\TipoDocumento#empleados refers to the owning side field Empleados\Entity\Empleado#tipodocumento which does not exist.

[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping fi le."

La relación es- muchos Empleados tienen un mismo TipoDocumento.

El código:

La clase Empleado (muchos a uno):

```
<?php
namespace Empleados\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as Collection;
use Empresas\Entity\Empresa;
use Empleados\Entity\TipoDocumento;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Documentos\Entity\Documentacion_Empleado;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleado")
 * 
 */

 class Empleado
 {
     /**
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=30,nullable=false,unique=true)
      */
     private $nro_documento;

    /*
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Empleados\Entity\TipoDocumento",inversedBy="empleados")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipodocumento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tipodocumento;

 //...

 }
```

La clase TipoDocumento (uno a muchos):

```
<?php
// la clase TipoDocumento esta en el mismo namespace que "Empleados"
namespace Empleados\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Empleados\Entity\Empleado;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tipo_documento")
 */

class TipoDocumento
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Empleados\Entity\Empleado", mappedBy="tipodocumento"))
     */
    private $empleados;

  //.....
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->empleados = new ArrayCollection();
    }

 }
```

Me estoy basando en el manual de Doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: `FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file` Has actualizado la base de datos? El campo `tipodocumento_id` existe en la tabla Empleado?

Comment: No existe, lo crea al hacer el mapeo. No se porque en el ejemplo del manual en la Clase Feature pone como referencia un campo "product_id" y luego abajo define un campo "product" que nunca es usado....

Comment: En el ejemplo, "product_id" hace referencia al nombre del campo en base de datos, mientras que product es el nombre de la propiedad de la clase, y a  la vez, del nombre de la relación.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Muriano muchas gracias por tu aporte que me guió a la solución que venía por el lado de los nombres y el case sensitive.

Lo que hice fué cambiar el nombre de la clase "TipoDocumento" por "Tipo_documento", con ese cambio la validación de mapeo estuvo OK.
Por alguna razón no le gustan los nombres camelcase a Doctrine ...

Como quedo el código:

Clase Empleado

```
 <?php
 namespace Empleados\Entity;

 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as Collection;
 use Empresas\Entity\Empresa;
 use Empleados\Entity\Tipo_documento;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Documentos\Entity\Documentacion_Empleado;

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="empleado")
  * 
  */

  class Empleado
  {
      /**
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
       */
      private $id;

      /**
       * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=30,nullable=false,unique=true)
       */
      private $nro_documento;

     /*
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Empleados\Entity\Tipo_documento",inversedBy="empleados")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipodocumento", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     private $tipodocumento;

  //...

  }
```

La clase "TipoDocumento" cambió a "Tipo_documento"

```
<?php
// la clase TipoDocumento esta en el mismo namespace que "Empleados"
namespace Empleados\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Empleados\Entity\Empleado;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tipo_documento")
 */

 class Tipo_documento
 {

     /**
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Empleados\Entity\Empleado", mappedBy="tipodocumento"))
      */
     private $empleados;

   //.....
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->empleados = new ArrayCollection();
     }

  }
```